# React Native: Continue animation with last velocity of touch gesture

Tags: animation, react-native

In my React Native application I have some tiles (wrapped in a `View` for the example) which are half of the full width wide. They act as buttons and slide to the opposite side to open a menu. When I perform a swipe gesture and release the finger before the slide reaches its final position, I want the slide to animate to its final 'opened' position. The animation should start with the last velocity of the touch gesture for a smooth impression.

I implemented different variations but did not find a good solution (You can find my [test-component in my GitHub repository](https://github.com/ca057/react-native-sliders/blob/master/testcomponent.js)). My `View` has a `PanResponder` to manage the gesture and to get the velocity. I started to use the `Animated` library, but the provided methods do not solve my problem. The only method where I can pass a initial velocity for the animation is the `decay`, but I can't pass a parameter where the animation should stop. With a `timing` animation I can set a final value, but can not pass a initial velocity (so the animation starts with a velocity of 0 which looks very jumpy). I tried to combine these two methods, but that does not work properly.

On iOS I could use a horizontal `ScrollView` with `pagingEnabled`, which shows the desired effect - but then I do not have the feature on Android.

Any ideas how I can solve this problem and show a smooth animation, starting with an initial velocity and ending on a given position, after the touch gestures end?

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT** I added the link to my last test component...

Comment: The pagingEnabled property in ScrollView for android is supported since 0.28, can you update your react-native and see if that solve your problem?

Comment: I'm sure you don't want this answer, but calculating velocity from position is easy.  So storing "currentVelocity" as points are fed to you should be easy.

Answer (score 5):

You can get a close approximation of the velocity by setting the `duration` of the timing animation

```
const duration = Math.abs((this.props.MAXDISTANCE - Math.abs(distanceMoved)) / velocity);
```

- `MAXDISTANCE` is your final position
- `distanceMoved` is the current position (`gestureState.dx`)
- `velocity` is the current velocity (`gestureState.vx`)

Comment: Can't agree with you, with this, you are assuming that the view will keep the same velocity, which is not correct

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Animated.decay](https://browniefed.com/react-native-animation-book/api/DECAY.html) or [Animated.spring](https://browniefed.com/react-native-animation-book/api/SPRING.html) to achieve this effect.